# Create whitelist for custom web browser in android 4.0

Tags: android, webview, browser, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, whitelist

I'm using webview to create a web browser for android. I keep my whitelist (php file that generates a xml file) inside my server, so I can modify it whenever I needed to. My app verifies if the url that is trying to access is in the whitelist, if not, then shows a dialog message. First I implemented it for android 2.3 and everything worked fine.
Now I need to implement it in android 4.0, but when I try to read the whitelist, it fails.

This is my declaration of my WebView

```
final WebView TBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    TBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    TBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    TBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    TBrowser.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
            boolean validUrl = false;

            try{
                URL website = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/whitelist.php);
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                HandlingXML whiteListHandler = new HandlingXML(host);
                xr.setContentHandler(whiteListHandler);

                xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));

                validUrl = whiteListHandler.isValid();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (validUrl) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }else{

            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())  
            .setTitle("ERROR")  
            .setMessage("URL not supported. Click on START OVER")   
            .setCancelable(true)  
            .create()  
            .show();  

            return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code for the xml handler:

```
public class HandlingXML extends DefaultHandler{

boolean validationResult = false;
String hostName;

public HandlingXML(String hn){
    hostName = hn;
}

public boolean isValid(){
    return validationResult;
}


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


    if (localName.equals("item") && !validationResult){
        if (attributes.getValue("data").equals(hostName)){
            validationResult = true;
        } else {
            validationResult = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this is the php that generates the xml:

```
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
echo "<whiteList>\n";

echo "<item data=\"www.facebook.com\"/>\n";
echo "<item data=\"m.facebook.com\"/>\n";
echo "<item data=\"api.twitter.com\"/>\n";
echo "<item data=\"plus.google.com\"/>\n";
echo "<item data=\"accounts.google.com\"/>\n";
echo "</whiteList>\n";
```

So, this works fine in android 2.3 but in 4.0 skips the try part (when reading and handling the whitelist).

What I found is that "...The reason why your application crashes on Android versions 3.0 and above, but works fine on Android 2.x is because HoneyComb and Ice Cream Sandwich are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread..."

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Now, can somebody help me figure out how work around this issue???

In the article mention about using a AsyncTask... I used to solve a similar issue:

changing from:

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent QuickRateIntent = new Intent(
                        "com.terillion.TERILLIONBROWSERACTIVITY");
                startActivity(QuickRateIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

To:

```
new timerAsync().execute();
```

And:

```
public class timerAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent QuickRateIntent = new Intent(
                            "com.terillion.TERILLIONBROWSERACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(QuickRateIntent);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
        return null;
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to make it work here. What changes do I need to make??? and where???

Comment: Did you read through that article that you mentioned...? It explains why this happens and what you can do.

Comment: I did it. Actually I used it to solve another issue I had (running a timer thread). But I can't figure out how to do it here. I added some extra explanation to the question.

Comment: Read through this to make sure you understand how and when to use AsyncTasks: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html. You should not be creating a new thread in one.